# Sqlite query Select only when equals two values

Tags: sqlite

```
"SELECT ? FROM TableSales....
```

I have two Columns, one is for Manufacturer and the other one is for Model.
I want to count how many times they exists in the table. The problem is to use a filter which only counts those, where the Manufacturer and the Model column are equal. Cause it could happen that the Model Column or the Manufacturer Column are equal but not both together.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're asking. Can you please share some sample data and the result you'd like to get?

Comment: "SELECT (Only those where Model and Manufacturer value are the same as "valueModel"and "value Manufacturer"), COUNT(*) AS '"+AString+"'   FROM SalesTable  where timeStamp BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+enddate+"'  ";

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you can accomplish the task with this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableSales WHERE Manufacturer == Model
```

Comment: I want to count how many rows the Table contains of a specific Combination of Model and Manufacturer. For example count all Apple(Manufacturer) iPhone(Model). Not Apple Macbook or Samsung iPhone. Its possible that the user uses the Model twice but from a different Manufacturer thats why i want to this